# Rewriting the URL's of 2 subfolders in a /public (root document) folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

Currently I have a "public" folder being root directory where all my frontend code goes.

But since my public folder contains both the website content and app content, I would like to split it more up. 
So my idea was:

```
.htaccess (rewriting public url)
src (php backend code)
public/
  web/
    index.php
  app/
    account.php
```

So my problem is, I can easily go to the pages like this:
http://example.com/web/index.php
http://example.com/app/account.php

but I would like to remove "web" and "app" from the URL's...
http://example.com/index.php
http://example.com/account.php
How can I do that using .htaccess? I'm running apache 2.4.
**EDIT**
An example of what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to tune up your requests. But a first approach is:

First, make sure that you have mod rewrite enabled.
Second, write the following in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[/]?index.php$ /web/index.php [NS,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[/]?account.php$ /app/account.php [NS,NC,L]
```

You will need to read the documentation to make other rules. You can read it here
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Also pay special attention on the flags. Read the documentation to set the ones that applies to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need a solution that's a bit more dynamic, so without actually typing the specific file as you did. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible. The rewrite rules uses Regexp. It is the most dynamic system ever. All the information is in the documentation. If you need an specific answer, post specific questions.

Comment: I've tried a lot of different things now, that's why I ask in here. I've updated my answer with an example of what i have tried, but still can't get it working.

Comment: The problem is the logic you are applying. I mean, the server needs a pattern to understand what to change. So if the server will receive /account,php it is easy to translate to /app/account.php. But if there are no difference between what the server gets from both kind of entries, better make a different subdomain. Like app.example.com and www.example.com. Then, when you have something in app.example.com, you rewrite it to example.com/app. So what you need is a way to distinguish both calls

Comment: Another idea that comes to me is to add a GET param to your app. So you can use QUERY_STRING with the regexp to identify it and, if it has it, you send it to /app. If it hasn't, you send it to /web ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. I was thinking about using the apache 2.4 if else statements and then rewriting the url depending on the request uri maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried so many different things now, but **I finally figured it out**.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite every web request
RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1"

# Rewrite every app request
RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/$1"

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works when having a setup:

```
public/ (root folder)<br>
   web/ (contains website frontend)<br>
   app/ (contains app frontend)<br>
   .htaccess (contains the code above)
```